# Transiting from real time to firestore loading data and displaying in text view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am in the process of moving my database from real-time to firestore and I am having some issues. Currently, I am attempting to load data from the database and have it displayed in a text view. This is what I am working with

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();

    db.collection("Users").document(current_uid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "hello did this work");
            String username = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
            mName.setText(username);

        }
    });
}
```

when i ran the debugger *username* is equal to null so I am believing that it is not receiving the data i have double checked the references. I also belive that it could be something to do with getting the UID but i am unsure and can't seem to figure out why it won't receive the data full class below

database:[image: database]

Where I'm at:

ok so I attached an authstate listeners to ensure I am getting the uid but the block of code inside of the listener is not being run and I can't figure out why. I have tried to use `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);` on the onStart but that did not work code I am working with

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //do i have to attach this listner?
    //mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            String currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().toString();

            db.collection("Users").document(currentUser).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "hello did this work");
                    String username = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                    mName.setText(username);

                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You should set up an auth state listener to get the UID whenever it becomes available instead of assuming it's immediately available.

Comment: but the user has to create an account before they can access this screen so the data is guaranteed to be there or am i missing the point.

Comment: It is not always guaranteed to be there.  Their validity of their identity token might still need to be verified, and that could take time.  Use a listener.

Comment: ok so i have created a authstate listener should i move the code i have in the snippet above in it or just use it to get the current user id

Comment: You should only query the database after the listener indicates that you have a signed in user with a uid.  This usually means that you do the work inside the listener, or as a result of something else it does.

Comment: added code to original post

Comment: You still have to check in the listener if the current user is not null, as the listener will get invoked for each transition between being signed in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out when I was adding the newly created user to the database i wasn't using the user id as the name of the document so when i was trying to reference it nothing was there i changed it so that when adding the user to the db it used the uid apposed to a random string.